# Http Post request resulted in end of stream

Tags: rest, http, neo4j, http-headers, resttemplate

I'm facing this weird issue. I'm running my application and Neo4j server on the local machine.

From the application, I'm making a POST request to begin a transaction in Neo4j (first line in the logs):

```html
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.headers) http-outgoing-0 >> POST /db/data/transaction/ HTTP/1.1
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.headers) http-outgoing-0 >> Accept: application/json, application/*+json
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.headers) http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Type: application/json
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.headers) http-outgoing-0 >> X-Stream: true
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.headers) http-outgoing-0 >> workSpaceId: NOT_AVAILABLE
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.headers) http-outgoing-0 >> neo4jRequestType: WRITE
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.headers) http-outgoing-0 >> threadUUID: 26b39600-abf1-440f-b08f-3350ee8ecdb1
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.headers) http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Length: 0
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.headers) http-outgoing-0 >> Host: localhost:7474
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.headers) http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.headers) http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.5 (java 1.5)
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.headers) http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-0 >> "POST /db/data/transaction/ HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept: application/json, application/*+json[\r][\n]"
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-0 >> "X-Stream: true[\r][\n]"
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-0 >> "workSpaceId: NOT_AVAILABLE[\r][\n]"
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-1 << "HTTP/1.1 201 Created[\r][\n]"
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-1 << "Location: http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/705[\r][\n]"
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-1 << "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-1 << "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *[\r][\n]"
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-1 << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-1 << "Server: Jetty(9.0.5.v20130815)[\r][\n]"
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-1 << "[\r][\n]"
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-1 << "96[\r][\n]"
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-5 << "HTTP/1.1 201 Created[\r][\n]"
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-5 << "Location: http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/704[\r][\n]"
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-1 << "{"commit":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/705/commit","results":[],"transaction":{"expires":"Wed, 18 Feb 2015 02:34:30 +0000"},"errors":[]}"
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-6 << "HTTP/1.1 201 Created[\r][\n]"
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-6 << "Location: http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/706[\r][\n]"
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-6 << "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-6 << "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *[\r][\n]"
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-6 << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-6 << "Server: Jetty(9.0.5.v20130815)[\r][\n]"
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-6 << "[\r][\n]"
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-6 << "96[\r][\n]"
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-6 << "{"commit":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/706/commit","results":[],"transaction":{"expires":"Wed, 18 Feb 2015 02:34:30 +0000"},"errors":[]}[\r][\n]"
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-6 << "0[\r][\n]"
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-0 >> "neo4jRequestType: WRITE[\r][\n]"
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-6 << "[\r][\n]"
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.headers) http-outgoing-1 << HTTP/1.1 201 Created
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.headers) http-outgoing-1 << Location: http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/705
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.headers) http-outgoing-1 << Content-Type: application/json
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.headers) http-outgoing-1 << Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.headers) http-outgoing-1 << Transfer-Encoding: chunked
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.headers) http-outgoing-1 << Server: Jetty(9.0.5.v20130815)
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-5 << "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-5 << "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *[\r][\n]"
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-5 << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.headers) http-outgoing-6 << HTTP/1.1 201 Created
18/02 13:33:31 DEBUG (http.headers) http-outgoing-6 << Location: http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/706
18/02 13:33:31 DEBUG (http.headers) http-outgoing-6 << Content-Type: application/json
18/02 13:33:31 DEBUG (http.headers) http-outgoing-6 << Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
18/02 13:33:31 DEBUG (http.headers) http-outgoing-6 << Transfer-Encoding: chunked
18/02 13:33:31 DEBUG (http.headers) http-outgoing-6 << Server: Jetty(9.0.5.v20130815)
18/02 13:33:31 DEBUG (execchain.MainClientExec) Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-0 >> "threadUUID: 26b39600-abf1-440f-b08f-3350ee8ecdb1[\r][\n]"
18/02 13:33:31 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Length: 0[\r][\n]"
18/02 13:33:31 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: localhost:7474[\r][\n]"
18/02 13:33:31 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-0 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
18/02 13:33:31 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.5 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
18/02 13:33:31 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
18/02 13:33:31 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
18/02 13:33:30 DEBUG (execchain.MainClientExec) Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
18/02 13:33:31 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-0 << "end of stream"
```

I got the response as "end of stream" (last line in the logs).

I checked the server http logs and it didn't had this request (searched using the threadUUID parameter from http headers). So, I don't get any transaction for this request.

I'm not able to figure out as what is this "end of stream" and what is the reason for it?

Also, I can see some timeouts:

```
18/02 13:34:30 DEBUG (http.wire) http-outgoing-8 << "[read] I/O error: Read timed out"
```

Any idea guys?

Comment: Check the log files `data/log` and `data/graph.db/messages.log`. Any exceptions there logged?

Comment: @StefanArmbruster - there were no issues in the logs.

Comment: hi. Did you find an explanation to this behavior? I see quite a lot of such log statements too.

Comment: @asgs - No, I resolved the issue for which I was analysing the logs so stopped looking into this.

Comment: @Rahul I'm also facing the same issue. Can you please share how did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening to us. It seems is normal the close connection and then the read timeout. I'm still investigating. In our case is even worse because we have requests after this that mixes the URL of one request (the one in progress) with the body of the other that may happen in different connection, different thread and 20 minutes ago...

So it's scaring.